# What happens if I truncate MSmerge_current_partition_mappings

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge-replication

We're still having massive issues with our Merge Replication (1 Publishers, 900 subscribers)

Inserting into certain tables can take up to 20 minutes and I'm trying to find a route cause.

Execution plans aren't really helping and what I have found out is that if I truncate MSmerge_current_partition_mappings the inserts are then quick,

We are in complete disaster mode right now so can some one tell me what will happen if I do that in production?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing around with data I don't understand I've ended up using this solution

```
BULK INSERT CustomView
FROM '\\directory\BulkInsertTest.txt'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR =',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
go  
sp_addtabletocontents 'BaseTable'
go
```

It cut the inserts down to less than a second and appears to be working.